# Android what is the purpose of using Local Service

Tags: android, service

In the Android official developer guide, the chapter of [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), there is an example about local binder which extends the Binder, the code is like this:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
// Binder given to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
// Random number generator
private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocalService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return LocalService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

/** method for clients */
public int getRandomNumber() {
  return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
}
```

}

And especially for this is the method for client to call:

```
/** method for clients */
public int getRandomNumber() {
  return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
}
```

I feel a bit confused about for such a simple action, why we need to put it to Service? What's further more is this Service is just a local service, can be only used in current process of application, but not other applications. Of course it is obviously this method can be put into any class as a public method, which is enough for the above case.

I can understand the purpose of to put such as file downloading code into a service (or maybe IntentService is a bit more suitable), which is suitable to the Service's feature: run long time processing code.

But what I cannot understand is why we need a Local Service like this?

Answer (score 2):

Local bind service is needed to handle client-server case

Suppose you have a case when you need to do some long operations many times and also need result of it and do some on result in your Activity.

In that case you bind service and use its method and also can use callback to get results and do operations in activity.

Comment: Thank you! But could you please provide an example for this 'client-server' case? Also I am wondering the use case and mechanism for 'use callbakc to get results and do operations in activity'.

Comment: And I can understand the case for client-server case when client and server in different processes, if client and server are in the same process, there are many other ways to do communication such as broadcast, static variable, or even they can call each other's methods directly, isn't it?